# Wirelessly *screen share* from any laptop to a wireless enabled TV

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, display, hdmi, tv

In my office I want to get a big TV for the meeting room that anyone can come in with any laptop and very simply be able to screen share to.

- Has to be wireless
- Has to be possible from any laptop old / new etc not driver dependant
- Would really prefer to not have to install software
- I would be happy to buy a device / media streamer / something with a USB key you could put in the laptop and just share with
- Have looked around a lot and most things reference video streaming or viewing folders of images, I need to just screen share for PowerPoint or documents etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options, both require installations:

- AppleTV and Airplay (free from Mac, you need to pay to get this working on [Windows](https://store.airsquirrels.com/))
- Miracast - comes with some TVs, still - you need to install drivers. [Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/project-wireless-screen-miracast) comes already with Miracast.

There is this as well but it will require connecting transmitter to teh laptop which you want to project from: [Wireless HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_HDMI) Few different products are available and reviews are mixed.

Soon you will be able to get [Airtame](http://airtame.com/) - no drivers, just a dongle. Should work from any HDMI connection.

Some people had success with mirroring desktop to Google's Chromecast - google it ;-)

Comment: Thanks - the AirTame looks perfect but unfortunately doesn't seem to be out until June and I need a solution now as mentioned I really want to stay away from stuff requiring software installed and drivers etc.    Anyone know of an AirTame alternative that's available now?

Comment: You can't cheat physics! What you are trying to achieve is very difficult physically: HDMI equals a lot of data. Cable bandwidth is different to current wireless bandwidth and without any compression it's difficult to send so much data over the air. Hence "drivers" - stuff which compresses, buffers etc screen to reduce amount of data do be sent.

Comment: Dam you physics!!! fair enough - the http://airtame.com/ looks perfect just a shame its not out yet.  Thanks for you help - answer accepted and have an upvote for good comms.

Comment: Thanks for your upvote, unfortunately there are bad news! Airtame still needs software installed! Please see this from their Indiegogo page: AIRTAME uses technology that's already in your computer - your Wi-Fi.

    Plug your AIRTAME into the HDMI port of your TV, projector or monitor and power it up through the USB cable.
    Install our AIRTAME application on your computer and from the menu bar you are able to see all AIRTAMEs that are nearby you. Choose which one to stream to and type in a password - if needed.